# Why can't I use filter for nested objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, object, filter

I am preparing a weather app that gives suggestion list as we enter an input city name.

Json file is in this format:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},
 "weather":[{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light intensity drizzle","icon":"09d"}],
  "base":"stations",
  "main":{"temp":280.32,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15},
"visibility":10000,
"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":80},
"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485789600,
"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0103,
"country":"GB",
"sunrise":1485762037,
"sunset":1485794875},
"id":2643743,
"name":"London",
"cod":200}
```

So my code for that functionality is:

```
inputcity.addEventListener("input",()=>getweather(inputcity.value));
const getweather=async searchtext=>{
    const res=await fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+inputcity.value+"&units=metric&appid=78a661b7c335021c7d85065aea3673be");
    const cities= await res.json();
    
   
let matches=cities.filter(city=>{
     const regex=new RegExp(`^${searchtext}`,'gi');
        return city.name.match(regex);
});
console.log(matches);
};
```

What I want is to show a list of city names starting with same letters.

But it's showing error the following error:

```
 *Uncaught (in promise)TypeError: cities.filter is not a function*
```

because this api gives data in **nested objects** not in **array of objects**.

How can get my code working using filter or any method?

Comment: Isn't it `cities.filter(....)` instead of `data`? And do you get an array from the API or a single object?

Comment: @Stutje yes ,it is cities. sorry for that and i have attached a sample of api data ,it is in nested objects

Comment: It's not an array and there's only one city anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because i don't have 50 reputation to leave a comment on the comment section.
I will just leave my comments here, so you can got an idea how to do it.

Your code that fetch the API's from `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+inputcity.value+"&units=metric&appid=78a661b7c335021c7d85065aea3673be` is only returning data for 1 city.

The returned data is also not a ARRAY, It's a JSON object.
See here for better viewing of your data : https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb13b4bd

For your idea about suggestion list on city name when users inputted the data, is not on their api's feature.

You should make a array for the city name lookup and shows the suggestion with `.startsWith(user.input)`.

Example super inefficient code to do that :

```
const userinput = "a";
var city = ["aaa", "abc", "bca", "cba", , "ccc"];
city.forEach(searchsuggestion);

function searchsuggestion(value, index) {
   if (value.startsWith(userinput)) {
      console.log("Suggestion : " + value);
   }
   else {
      return;
   }
}
```

Your Console output for the above code should be :

```
Suggestion : aaa
Suggestion : abc
```